PCRaster Convert to PCRaster Format Problems
I have installed PCRaster library and plug-in and am trying to convert my GeoTIFF to PCRaster format using PCRaster Convert to PCRaster Format.  I'm getting the following error.
QGIS version: 3.34.6-Prizren
QGIS code revision: 623828f5
Qt version: 5.15.13
Python version: 3.12.3
GDAL version: 3.8.5
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.4.0, March 1st, 2024
PDAL version: 2.6.3 (git-version: 816ce1)
PCRaster version: QGIS PCRaster Provider version 0.3.0
Algorithm started at: 2024-04-28T15:58:02
Algorithm 'Convert to PCRaster Format' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/smill/Documents/LiDAR_2017_3084408.tif', 'INPUT2' : 0, 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/000WORKIndexedTasks 000-999/500 Papers/502 Revisiting DEM Infilling/Data/PCR_DEM.map' }
Execution completed in 0.10 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/000WORKIndexedTasks 000-999/500 Papers/502 Revisiting DEM '
'Infilling/Data/PCR_DEM.map'}
Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/000WORKIndexedTasks 000-999/500 Papers/502 Revisiting DEM Infilling/Data/PCR_DEM.map
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
I looked at Log Messages Panel and found this:
2024-04-28T15:45:00     WARNING    “.” files are not supported as outputs for this algorithm
So I made sure that I specified a permanent output file named PCR_DEM.map.

Did you type the output file name directly into the box, or did you use the file explorer dialog? I find that sometimes when I type directly into the box I get failures like this.
